# How can I redirect foreigners by IP to other URL in WordPress?

Tags: redirect

I want that visitors out of my country would be redirected to www.mysite.com/en. How I can do this in Wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using:

http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php

Send a get with the incoming ip adress and based on the response redirect it to a different part of your website.

```
$request = new WP_Http;
$result = $request->request( 'http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-country/?key=<your_api_key>&ip=74.125.45.100' );
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: As an addendum, the OP would want to use the `init` hook and place the code in that. Also, use `wp_redirect()` function to redirect the user.